# Adding a column of the same character name for all the rows in matlab

Tags: matlab, datatable, data-processing

I have a table in MATLAB that I'd like to add a column that contains a character variable that's the same throughout the column, but different size lengths. Here's a code for two random tables.

```
r1 = rand(100,1);
r1 = array2table(r1);
r1.Properties.VariableNames = {'Random1'};

r2 = rand(54,1);
r2 = array2table(r2);
r2.Properties.VariableNames = {'Random2'};
```

Is there a way, for example, for me to add a column named 'Time' that contains the character 'hours' for both based on the number of rows of the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add the new array to your tables:

```
r1.Time = repmat('hours', [length(r1.Random1), 1]);
r2.Time = repmat('hours', [length(r2.Random2), 1]);
```